# Error when using Map in Pure Function

Tags: map

I'm trying to solve [Project Euler 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21)

My solution is as follows:

```
amicable[n_]:=If[Nest[Total[Most[Divisors[#]]]&,n,2]==n,n,0]
Total[Map[amicable[#]&,Range[10000]]]
```

When I run this code on Wolfram Cloud I get the following error:

```
Divisors:Divisors called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected

In[45]:= $Version
Out[45]= 11.2.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)
```

The code still runs and returns an answer but I'm curious as to how that's possible

Comment: use `Range[2,10000]` in place of  `Range[10000]`; the input value `1` is giving `0` i the first step of `Nest[...]` and `Most@Divisors[0]` is generating the error in the second step.

Comment: Just a follow up on @kglr's point, since this is a somewhat subtle bug. `Most@h[a.., b]` is `h[a]`. `Divisors` isn't defined for `0` so Mathematica just spits `Divisors[0]` back out. Same with `Divisors[]`, although Mathematica emits a helpful warning first. Finally, `Total` ignores the `Head` so `Total@h[a..]` is effectively just `Plus[a]` thus `Total@Divisors[]` is `Plus[]` which is defined to be `0` and so the check with `==` still works, even though if it were non numeric it would not.

Comment: Your second line can be shortened to `Total[amicable /@ Range[2, 10000]]`